# Чем плоха система include, и чем можно ее заменить

Tags: c++, c

Собственно, хотелось бы обсудить следующий вопрос.
Все мы знаем, что в языках Си и Си++, широко используется ключевое слово препроцессора #include, которое позволяет вставлять код так называемых заголовочных файлов в тело основной программы, и таким образом, позволять одним модулям видеть объявления из другого модуля, и, соответсвенно маршалить код друг друга.

Также где-то я видел упоминание (то ли в топиках на хабре при обсуждении языка D, то ли где-то здесь, на хешкоде), что, мол, сия система крайне плоха, и сильно уступает аналогам в лице using и пр.

Собсно вопрос: а в чем ее недостатки?

Comment: > и чем можно ее заменить

Многопроходной компиляцией, как в современных языках. Вы что, пишете свой язык?

Comment: Нет, при чем здесь.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. include'идить можно произвольный файл - не только *.h, но и *.c и *.cpp, и вообще что угодно, т.к. это ф-ция препроцессора, а не компилятора. Соответственно, включаемый файл "гадит" в глобальном namespace файла, в который он включается. Ес-но если не предпринимать каких-либо дополнительных мер.
2. include не отслеживает сколько раз был включен один и тот же файл заголовка. Соответственно, это становится головной болью программиста, но есть два решения - директива препроцессора `#pragma once` или использование т.н. [include guards](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)
3. очень тяжело соптимизировать процесс включения заголовочных файлов, т.к. это получается древовидная зависимость. Есть костыли, которые эту проблемы пытаются решать, например, [предкомпилированные заголовки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), но в некоторых случаях они создают дополнительные проблемы.
4. невозможность [экспортировать шаблоны](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2+c%2B%2B).
5. Так же необходимость определять все шаблоны (да и инлайновые ф-ции) в заголовочных файлах. В конечном счете, это ведет к грандиозному увеличению времени компиляции.
6. Отсутствие контроля за версиями включаемых файлов.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Добавлю ещё такую проблему: различные директивы препроцессора могут поменять смысл текста в `.h`-файле. Например:

    #define private public
    #define protected public
    #define class struct
    #include "header"
    #undef class
    #undef protected
    #undef private

Comment: Ещё: программист либо обязан либо открывать на всеобщее обозрение список своих private- и protected-полей и функций, либо пользоваться довольно громоздким паттерном pimpl.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что using все эти проблемы решает?

Comment: @DonEladio Если речь про ключевое слово `using`, то нет конечно. Если же речь про другие способы организации модульной системы сборки в других языках программирования, то их нельзя рассматривать в отрыве от самих языков. И там есть свои плюсы и недостатки.